# try and except in python in case program terminate

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need try and except help or any other best way to archive my requirement. Please help

```
  mount_status = check_output (["mount", "/dev/sr{}".format(x), "/mnt"])
```

Provides following output:

```
   1. If medium does not found then below messages appears and stops the program.



mount: no medium found on /dev/srX
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    software_foundation()
  File "test.py", line 31, in software_foundation
    mount_status = check_output (["mount", "/dev/sr{}".format(x), "/mnt"])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mount', '/dev/srX', '/mnt']' returned non-zero exit status 32






2. If medium exits but it already mounted then below messages appears and stops the program.
mount: /dev/srX is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/srX is already mounted or /mnt busy
       /dev/srX is already mounted on /mnt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 39, in <module>
    software_foundation()
  File "test1.py", line 31, in software_foundation
    mount_status = check_output (["mount", "/dev/sr{}".format(x), "/mnt"])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mount', '/dev/srX', '/mnt']' returned non-zero exit status 32
```

If I get option 1 then it should continue

If I Get option 2 then it should terminate program.

What i tried is in below script and it is not working

```
from subprocess import check_output
import os
def Mounting():
    print "Mounting"
    print "Mount CD and Press Enter"
    raw_input ("Press Enter to continue...")
    for x in range(0,5):

        mount_status = check_output (["mount", "/dev/sr{}".format(x), "/mnt"])

        if mount_status.strip() == "mount: /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only":
            break
        elif "is already mounted on /mnt" in mount_status.strip():
            print "/mnt has already mounted. Unmount /mnt and rerun the script"
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your question that you don't know how to write a `try...except`.

Put `try` before the line that is raising the exception you want to trap. Put `except` before the `if`-tests that work out how to handle the exception.

```
import subprocess 
import sys 

for x in range(0,5):
    try:
        mount_status = subprocess.check_output (["mount", "/dev/sr{}".format(x), "/mnt"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as details:
        if "is write-protected, mounting read-only" in details: 
            break
        elif "is already mounted on /mnt" in details:
            print "/mnt has already mounted. Unmount /mnt and rerun the script"
            sys.exit()
```

It doesn't help to check `mount_status` in your `if`-test, because that only gets a value if your call to `check_output()` succeeds. If the return code from the command is non-zero, `check_output()` raises an exception instead, and so the assignment to `mount_status` never happens.